# UipickerView how to know when it stops moving

Tags: iphone

I am facing a problem with UIpickerview. In my app I implemented an uipickerview for displaying the country list, I add a toolbar above the uipickerview that having two buttons (Cancel and DONE). If i press Cancel it simply hides the uipickerview and all is fine.
But if I use DONE button I get the value of selected row from component and hides the pickerview it works fine problem arise if someone moves the countrylist very fast as he can, suddenly he press DONE button then uipickerview hides but did not return the selected row value from component. Thats my problem..

It may handle if i can track when picker movement stops then need to display DONE button otherwise (in case of moving state ) DONE button will be hidden.

Can some one have any idea or any alternate way to solve this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```
[myPickerView addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerDidStop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Here the pickerDidStop method will be called once the picker stops scrolling. U can do watever u want inside that method.

Happy coding ! Cheers!!

Comment: -addTarget:action:forControlEvents: is a UIControl method, but UIPickerView is derived from UIView. Instance of UIPickerView does not respond to this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a global variable and by using following method:

```
 -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

You can assign the value to that global variable.
And then by checking condition on that Done button for the global variable you can do operations as you like.